# VBA Cell values as date range for file selection from folder

Tags: vba, excel, date

I hope you can help I currently have a piece of code (see below) that allows a user to select a folder. The code then opens up **all** the workbooks in that folder, selects a specific sheet, sheet named "SearchCaseResults" from each workbook book copies the data on this sheet and then pastes it to another sheet "Disputes" in another Workbook in another folder.

This all works perfectly, but what I want to happen now is that instead of opening up every workbook in the folder. I only want it to open up Workbooks in the folder based on the Cell Values of B6 and B7 which I have made into a Date Picker see Pic 1 for better understanding.

So instead of the piece of code that states do while folder is not blank

```
Do While myFile <> ""
```

I would like it to say something like

```
Do While myFile >= "B6" And myFile <= "B7"
```

The above piece of code compiles but does not work unfortunately

Can my code be amended to only open Workbooks in the date range set out in Cells B6 and B7

I have run out of online resources and have search for answers to this for days so I am reaching out for assistance

As always any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Pic 1 
[image]

MY CODE

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim y As Workbook




'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
    .Title = "C:\Users\CONNELLP\Desktop\Claire Macro\Copy and Paste Disputes\Looper\"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

Set y = ThisWorkbook
Set ws2 = y.Sheets("Disputes")

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""

    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Copy data on "SearchCaseResults" sheet to "Disputes" Sheet in other workbook
    With wb.Sheets("SearchCasesResults")
        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A2:M" & lRow).Copy ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
    End With

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    'Get next file name
    myFile = Dir
Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Pic of folder

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, are the workbooks in the folder named as dates or are you trying to open ones created/edited between those dates?

Comment: If you're just after *Last Modified*, you could use `FileDateTime ( file_path )`

Comment: at Ben: Hi Ben there is no date in the file name see new pic of folder in edited part of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for files last modified between the dates in B6 and B7, then swap this into your current loop:

```
Do While myFile <> ""

    If Int(FileDateTime(myPath & myFile)) >= Range("B6").Value And _
        Int(FileDateTime(myPath & myFile)) <= Range("B7").Value Then

        'Set variable equal to opened workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

        'Copy data on "SearchCaseResults" sheet to "Disputes" Sheet in other workbook
        With wb.Sheets("SearchCasesResults")
            lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("A2:M" & lRow).Copy ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        End With

        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    End If

    'Get next file name
    myFile = Dir
Loop
```

If however, you wanted to compare the *filename itself* to the date in the cell, you're going to need to show us the filename's format for us to help.

Comment: CLR: Once again you save this Irishman's butt :-) Thank you so much again for the assistance it is greatly appreciated. Much respect from Dublin :-) Hoping you have a great day.